# Easy way to convert Julian calendar to standard with Python xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray, python-datetime, julian-date

I'm new to Python and I'm using xarray. My netcdf file contains data with time given in 'days since 0001-01-01 00:00:00', calendar type is Julian. Does anybody know an easy way to convert the time to standard calendar?

Thanks in advance :)

```
xarray.Dataset.convert_calendar()
```

didn't work for me

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(Dataset.time, "%Y %m %d %H %M")
```

and similar also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert Julian dates to a standard calendar (usually Gregorian) in xarray using `cftime` library. Here's a minimal example:

1. Install `cftime`: `pip install cftime`
2. Convert time coordinates.

```py
import xarray as xr
import cftime

# Load your dataset
ds = xr.open_dataset('your_file.nc')

# Convert Julian to standard calendar (e.g., Gregorian)
ds['time'] = xr.coding.times.decode_cf_datetime(ds['time'], calendar='gregorian')

# Now ds['time'] is in Gregorian
```

Note: Replace `'your_file.nc'` with your NetCDF file path.

Hope that helps!